# python django - search and get dictionary

Tags: python

`data['objects']` gives me this:

```
[{u'id': 8299, u'title': u'Blablablabla text',
 u'url': u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuPBjf3jq_M', u'video_id': u'EuPBjf3jq_M', 
 u'slug': u'my-slug', u'thumbnail': u'/media/CACHE/images/bilder/2014/09/12/133107_VMi5c/656141a37cc52e347c14e4837d39c1e3.jpg'}, 
{...},{...}, ..]
```

There are many dictionaries like the one above. I need to find the one which has the slug `my-slug` using python.

how can I search and get the whole dictionary which contains this slug?

Comment: Looks like pure python, why do you mention django? Is data is some queryset?

Comment: @stalk i removed django, for now, i dont have querysets thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> data = [{u'id': 8299, u'title': u'Blablablabla text',
 u'url': u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuPBjf3jq_M', u'video_id': u'EuPBjf3jq_M', 
 u'slug': u'my-slug', u'thumbnail': u'/media/CACHE/images/bilder/2014/09/12/133107_VMi5c/656141a37cc52e347c14e4837d39c1e3.jpg'}, 
{'slug': 'no'}, {'title': 'just_title'}]
>>> filter(lambda x: x.get('slug') == 'my-slug', data)
[{u'title': u'Blablablabla text', u'url': u'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuPBjf3jq_M', u'video_id': u'EuPBjf3jq_M', u'slug': u'my-slug', u'id': 8299, u'thumbnail': u'/media/CACHE/images/bilder/2014/09/12/133107_VMi5c/656141a37cc52e347c14e4837d39c1e3.jpg'}]
```

Also, if your data set is big, it is better to use [`ifilter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter), as it won't create new list, but generator:

```
>>> from itertools import ifilter
>>> filtered_generator = ifilter(lambda x: x.get('slug') == 'my-slug', data)
>>> 
>>> filtered_generator
<itertools.ifilter object at 0x7f0830be7fd0>
>>> 
>>> for d in filtered_generator:
...     print d['slug']
... 
my-slug
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way ?

```
>>> objs = [{'slug': 'my-slug', ...},{'slug': 'xxx', ...}, ...]
>>> (filter(lambda o: o['slug'] == 'my-slug', objs) or [None])[0]
{'slug': 'my-slug'}
```

Comment: This is good, but it will fail if any dictionary doesn't have the key `slug` with a `KeyError` - @stalk's answer uses the get() method of dictionaries which returns `None` if the key doesn't exist, rather than raising a `KeyError`.

Comment: It was only a sketch, but you're right - I should be more accurate. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of objects that have that slug:

```
right_slug = [obj for obj in data['objects'] if obj['slug'] == 'my-slug']

if len(right_slug) == 1:
    the_object = right_slug[0]
else:
    # Oh no, the slug occurred either 0 or more than 1 times!
    # do something here
    pass
```